# How to call liveData observer from another liveData observer

Tags: android, android-livedata

I am working on livedata. I have two apis but one api is dependent on another api. Based on first api response i am calling another api using livedata observer. I am calling from inside observer is this a right approach or any other alternative

```
  mainViewModel.getListLiveData().observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<List<Student>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Student> list) {
                if(list.size() > 0){
                    mainViewModel.getStudentLiveData().observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<Student>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable Student student) {

                        }
                    });   
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: It would be better if you only observe the final answer rather than doing it like this. Instead, make your nested API call in your repository class and pas the final result to your ViewModel. If you are using RXjava it would be easier to make nested API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Observe on the student `LiveData` exposed by the `mainViewModel`. In the viewmodel make student live data change with change in List LiveData using `Transformations` or using a `MediatorLiveData`

In your activity:

```
mainViewModel.getStudentLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<Student>() {
   student -> {}
});
```

In your viewmodel:

```
private MutableLiveData<List< Student>> studentListLiveData = new MutableLiveData(); // this will hold result of your first api call

private MutableLiveData<Student> studentLiveData = new MutableLiveData(); // this will hold result of your second api call


private void fetchData() {
    fetchStudentList(new Callback {
      result -> { 
           studentListLiveData.value = result; 
           fetchStudent(new Callback {
               result -> { studentLiveData.value = result; }
           });      
      }
    })
}

public LiveData<Student> getStudentLiveData() {
      return studentLiveData;
}
```

Comment: Cannot provide an exact code until I see your API calls :/

Comment: Edited to provide some code. You will have to change this to your exact impl.

Comment: this code won't work in my scenario, i am displaying student list in spinner and i need to display specific student in spinner. both are livedata values but i am trying to do livedata observe sequentially but it is not happening, that's why i am getting first spinner list then i am selecting specific student in spinner